# jshint ignoring some entries in my .jshintignore file

Tags: jshint

My .jshintignore file looks like this:

```
node_modules/**
coverage/**
public/js/lib/**
doc/**
plato/**
```

The first 2 lines work well to ignore everything under node_modules/ and coverage/

However the next 3 lines are not respected by jshint and files from those 3 directories are being included in the jshint analyses...

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
node_modules/**/*
coverage/**/*
public/js/lib/**/*
doc/**/*
plato/**/*
```

I think it should then ignore files recursively below the directory that you specify

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing `/**`?

`node_modules
coverage
public/js/lib
doc
plato`

That way it should ignore those directories, effectively ignoring everything else inside them.